# Existence of a programming language - guaranteed termination

Tags: programming-languages

Does there exist a programming language, where you always are guaranteed a termination?

If you only have if/else statements can you then be sure that that a program will terminate?

Comment: I think, perhaps, review the [Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) and the relation to Turing machines and what it means for a programming language to be "turing complete": "The halting problem is a decision problem about properties of computer programs on a fixed Turing-complete model of computation, i.e. all programs that can be written in some given programming language that is general enough to be equivalent to a Turing machine." (Of course, if a language is *not* TC then... besides not being very useful for general programming...)

Comment: Why close votes? It is a perfectly valid question for SO.

Comment: @pst, non-Turing-complete languages are *very* useful for general programming. There are not that much problems that can't be solved in, say, Coq.

Comment: @SK-logic Have an example of it being used for "general programming"? (Perhaps we have different definitions ;-)

Comment: @pst, a complete C compiler is "general" enough? This one is written in Coq: http://compcert.inria.fr/compcert-C.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, of course there are some non-Turing-complete languages that do guarantee a termination (or at least provide subsets with such a guarantee):

- [ACL2](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~moore/acl2/)
- [Coq](http://coq.inria.fr/)
- [Agda2](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php) and alike

In most cases, it is achieved by only allowing recursive calls over strict sub-terms (and, with Church arithmetics, it implies always decreasing positive integer counters as well).

And, surprisingly, this is not as limiting as it looks, and these languages are perfectly suitable for a very wide range of problems.

The [Terminator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Terminator) project could be interesting as well.

Answer (score 3):

A programming language that guarantees termination is not [turing complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness). [Otherwise, the [Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), would be a trivial problem, which is proven to be not the case for turing machines].

You might refer to [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) as a weak programming language for this issue, and it is has the feature you seek.

Comment: Our languages may be turing complete, but we are not using turing machines.

Comment: @Shahbaz You can simulate a turing machine with any turing complete language, therefore if you find a turing complete language which guarantees halting, you trivially get this contradiction.

Comment: I said, our computers are not turing machines. They have finite memory, therefore finite number of states. Believe it or not, our computers are just big DFAs. Even though the languages may be turing complete, they are not being run on a turing machine.

Comment: Actually I completely disagree with this interpretation of the Halting Problem. The theorem refers to arbitrary programs. People don't write arbitrary programs. I would contend, on the contrary, that a good programming language, which can express just about anything, can always be proven to terminate. The reason is simple: the programmer that wrote it has a reason to believe it terminates, and a way to explain why they think that. In a "good" language they could actually write that proof and have it verified.

Comment: @Yttrill — (a) Certain programs *shouldn't* terminate; web servers, for example, or nuclear power plant control systems. (b) Whether or not your statement is true, it's not related to what amit's saying. If you have a language in which every program terminates, then you can solve the halting problem in that language trivially, as `halts(program, input) = True`. This implies, by contraposition of the Halting Problem, that the language in question is *not* Turing complete. amit is not saying anything about the Turing completeness of other languages, or the interpretation of Turing completeness.

Comment: I don't see how the conclusion actually follows, even though it looks like it does at first by @wchargin's argument. The halting problem proof works for turing machines, but here, the hypothesis is "what if you have a programming language such that every program in it terminates." In particular it is impossible to construct the counter-example program which is used to prove the halting problem for turing machines.

Answer (score 3):

[Datalog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datalog) is an example of a real programming language for which every program terminates.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot predict if a program will ever stop for a general case of a program (this is what is called "[The Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)").

A "standard" programming language is equivalent to a Turing machine, thus you cannot predict whether a program written on this language will stop.

If you limit your programming language, the terms change, and in some cases the halting program for such a model may be solvable, but this is not the case for a general-usage programming language.

Comment: It does not belong to cstheory, this site if for research level questions.

Comment: @amit - no site for undergrads? This is a pretty basic computation theory question, but SO doesn't seem to be the place for it..

Comment: It's Turing not Touring.

Comment: maybe programmers... but definetly not cstheory, as the [FAQ](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/faq) indicate: "Theoretical Computer Science - Stack Exchange is for theoretical computer scientists and researchers in related fields. We welcome research-level questions in theoretical computer science (TCS)."

Answer (score 1):

As you already saw (in other answers), a program which is as powerful as a turing machine, cannot be predicted if it halts or not. Although our computers are not turing machines (they are barely linear bounded automata, and if you really want to be precise, they are just DFAs with a HUGE number of states. This is because of the finite memory)

So **in theory, you can** determine if any program in our conventional computers can halt or not. That program however may require `O(2^(32)*n)` (n being the size of the memory) memory and time which is **practically impossible**. (If you want the algorithm, run the program and save the state of the whole memory at each step, check if ever you reach the same snapshot of the memory. Since the memory is limited, this algorithm will stop).

So now the question boils down to what are the properties of a language that are predictable, in say, polynomial time. Answering this question is not so easy, but a few examples easily come to mind:

- A program that doesn't have a loop, always stops
- A program that uses small enough amount of memory, can be inspected whether it halts or not. Unfortunately, this, at least in a naive way, requires running that algorithm I mentioned above for every possible initial state, which means that small amount of memory might as well be like 10 bytes!

A program written in a language that always halts, would be an extremely weak algorithm. The reason being that you cannot reach the same state ever. If you do, you *can* get stuck in a loop. Imagine a game written in that language, when you walk around, if you step on some tile twice, the game dies. Even a simple program that gets two numbers and prints the sum and then repeat cannot be written.

Finally, perhaps the least stupid of those always-halting languages would be one that is like our normal languages, but just kills the program after, say, 7 days.

Comment: Nevertheless, most modern programming languages are considered turing complete, You can theoretically bound everything, since there are a finite number of atoms in the universe, it makes everything O(1).

Comment: @amit, quite the contrary, an algorithm that goes through an array is `O(n)`. The fact that in this universe you cannot make `n` bigger than a certain value, is just a practicality matter. It is in **practice** that you can bound everything by the number of atoms in the universe, not in **theory**.

Comment: @amit, Just so you know, the problem here is not impossibility, but exponential time. Have you ever heard of quantum computing? Did you know the RSA is also based on the fact that finding primes that made the key is exponential in time? Did you know that if they ever build a real quantum computer, solving that would be easy as hell? You cannot say this is impossible. It is only impractical with current technology.

Comment: @Shahbaz: Just so you know .. you're wrong. Iterating an array of fixed length is O(1). The O notation only applies to programs parametrized by variable bounds, and measures performance as the bound is increased to infinity. Since all real computers have fixed bounds, the O notation does not apply to any real programs. There is nothing to stop theoretical models introducing bounds so they're useful for practical problems. Many C++ Standard Library algorithms have mandatory performance requirements.

Comment: @Yttrill, I understand you. In the real-world, you can say that every algorithm is theoretically O(1), simply because the size of input is bounded by some constant (no matter how huge). The reason we use the O notation is that, although O talks about asymptotically large n, in practice the behaviour is visible for every-day size of n. For example, an algorithm that is O(n) is **more or less** 100 times faster when given input of size 1000 than 100,000, although theoretically that may not have been true. I don't understand, what part of what I had said contradicted anything you said?

Comment: @Shahbaz: what you say is only partially true. First, the constant matter a lot, and it often dominates: often the fastest code is has bad O performance but it doesn't matter because the problem size is fixed. For problems smaller than the bound no one cares, and larger problems can't run anyhow. Example: many compilers like mine have a lot of exponential time algorithms in them but it doesn't matter because they're analysing source code which is necessarily small.

Comment: @Yttrill, What part of what I said implied to you that I am saying otherwise?

Comment: Secondly, there are some data structures such as Judy arrays which have poor theoretical performance and literally wipe out all the others. In fact Judy arrays don't have asymptotic performance because they're intrinsically bound to the machine word size: they have ultra-fast real performance because they're tuned to optimise cache use. Judy array (trie = digital tree) kills a balanced tree dead in the water for all operations. A badly written digital tree is hundreds of times slower (I know, I wrote one!)

Comment: @Shahbaz: I'm just taking exception to your distinction between theory and practice. In practice, and therefore in any good theory, bounds matter. Constants matter. The O notation is only a guide.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hard question, as it depends on what your definition of a programming language is.  One possible definition requires that it must be possible to simulate any Turing machine using that language (ignoring the practical limits caused by the finite memory of actual machines).  If your definition includes that requirement, or its equivalent, then the answer is no, as there are Turing machines that do not halt for some inputs.

However, there are restricted computer languages that could reasonably called programming languages (ignoring the requirement discussed above), at least in principle (I do not know if they have actually been implemented).  One such language is what I call a for-language: it supports straight-line programs, if-then-else clauses and restricted loops of the form

```
for i = E1 to E2 step E3
   ... code ...
end for
```

in which the induction variable `i` is non-assignable (and where a pointer to `i` cannot be formed).  The reason such a language can express only terminating programs is that there is a maximum number of iterations that each loop can take, known at the start of the loop.

Quite many programs could be written using a language similar to the for-language, but there are some computing problems that could not be.  A famous example is, I believe, computing the Ackerman function.